# Strange convergence of numerical Buffon's needle

Tags: probability, numerical-methods

I was wondering how this behavior is called and its explanation (or where I can find an explanation of this phenomenon)

[image]

The behavior I'm taking about is that sometimes, when the number of throws of the needle is incremented (here the step has been chosen to be 1000) the absolute error increases! There is an overall tendency for the overall error to approximate zero, but there are fluctuations and I'm sure there is a way to calculate important properties of these fluctuations.

Important background:

Buffons needle experiment consists of $\pi$ as $\pi = \frac{2}{n/N}$ where $n$ is the number of throws of a needle, and $N$ is the number of times it crosses a line. See [Buffons needle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffon%27s_needle)

Thanks.

If you're not so sure what this graph is representing:

Absolute error (y axis); Number of throws of Buffons needle (x axis); The code has been chosen so that at each new iteration of the experiment, the experimenter throws the needle and additional 1000 times.

Comment: Have you tried replicating this plot several times? Do these jumps are always of comparable height or maybe sometimes they are smaller or bigger?

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to diagnose what's going on without reproducible code but I think you're just seeing typical statistical fluctuations. For Buffon's needle problem, the [variance around the proportion (see 14)](http://www.randomservices.org/random/buffon/Buffon.html) $\pi$ scales something like $\frac{1}{2n}$ where $n$ is the number of throws, so that's why the fluctuations decrease but not incredibly fast.

For example you see a fluctuation $0.01$ around $10^4$ throws, and the expected standard deviation is around $\sqrt{1/2\cdot 10^4}=0.007$ which reasonably explains the jump. Go ahead and try to plot curves $i/\sqrt{2n}$ for $i=1,2,3$ to check this for all values.